# VUE Count how many directives are used on a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

I've tried to count how many `directives` are used on a component like this. But it does not work as I expected

this is my directive file

```
import ahoy from "ahoy.js"

let count = 0

export default {
  id: "bar",
  definition: {
    bind: (el, binding) => {
      const handler = (entries, observer) => {
        count++
        console.log(count)
        if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            ahoy.track("impression", {
              ...(typeof binding.value === "object"
                ? { ...binding.value }
                : { value: binding.value }),

              page: document.title,
              path: window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/en\//g, "/"),
              class: el.classList.value
            })

            observer.unobserve(entries[0].target)
          }, 100)
        }
      }

      const createIntersection = new IntersectionObserver(handler, { rootMargin: "-45% 0%" })
      createIntersection.observe(el)
    }
  }
}
```

and this is how I call `directive` on my component

```
ReviewCard(
  v-bar="createIntersection(foo)"
)
```

variable count not stored `val++`

how can I count how many directives are used on a component?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It seems that you are intentionally reducing all of your questions too much. Please don't. You are not supposed to change questions which have answers. StackOverflow wants to also keep good though old Q/A pairs. If you have special reasons for wanting to delete your questions please flag them for moderator attention and explain there why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count++` is currently in `handler`, which is passed to the `IntersectionObserver`, so `count` would only be incremented upon an intersection. That update should probably be moved outside of `handler` to the root of the `bind()` call:

```js
export default {
  definition: {
    bind: (el, binding) => {
      count++

      const handler = /*...*/
      //...
    }
  }
}
```